# Change Entity Framework public default constructors to internal

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So I have a simple enough problem, but I cant seem to solve it properly.

I am using EF 6 and used a model first method to define my entities and generate the DB.
The problem is that the default constructors are public, and I wish to change them to internal while also providing overloaded constructors that will be used by the other projects in my solution.

How can I prevent the usage of the default constructors outside of my assembly ?

I thought of simply modifying the entities but then any modification to the model would regenerate the entities and I would have to redo the modifications.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can't you just modify the T4 templates that are used to generate the entities?

Comment: For the default constructor part, why don't you create them as protected instead?

Comment: Yeah I would try modifying the template, but I cant seem to find that part in the template. And to Sebastian, how could I modify them to protected ? Protected or internal, its the same thing, I dont know where to modify it